# Controller - No access in class - Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I got this error message, but I don't really understand why.

```
Neither the property "categories" nor one of the methods "addCategory()"/"removeCategory()", "setCategories()", "categories()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Item".
```

The thing is, in my entity "Item" I really have all of this stuff:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Category", mappedBy="items")
 **/
private $categories;
```

and

```
/**
 * Add categories
 *
 * @param Category $categories
 * @return Item
 */
public function addCategory(Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove categories
 *
 * @param Category $categories
 */
public function removeCategory(Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
}

/**
 * Get categories
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->categories;
}
```

Okay, okay - and what is in my Controller?

```
/**
 * Creates a new Item entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="item_create")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Item();
    $currentUser = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
        ->add('name', null, array(
            'label' => 'Item Name',
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Select a Category',
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'CheckoutItemBundle:Category',
            'property' => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where('c.user = :user')
                    ->setParameter('user', $currentUser);
            },
        ))

        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Speichern'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();


    }

    return $this->render(
        'CheckoutItemBundle:Item:create.html.twig',
        array(
            'entity' => 'entity',
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

So, the big question is, why he say that he didn't find it, when it is obviously there. Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your mapping without error ? You can check it with `doctrine:schema:validate`. That would make sure it's not your ManyToMany relation giving trouble, like I suspect it is.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and help. I checked already this aspect, no errors. :-)

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Either through the command line or by deleting the folders yourself?

Comment: I did `app/console cache:clear` - error still there.

Comment: Try deleting the `cache/dev` and eventually the `cache/prod` folders then. Sometimes that makes a difference.

Comment: Okay, I did. Still there. I really think, it is something else. I think it has something to do with an wrong 'property' or so. But I'm right now only in the beginning to understand, where the error maybe came from...

Comment: I would try to implement `setCategories` and see if it makes the error go away. Delete the cache folders every time you make a change, just in case.

Comment: It helped by adding `__toString(....)` - WTF? In the documentation it's clear: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property - only WITHOUT property, you have to put in `__toString()` - so why is the solution now `__toString` AND `property`???

Comment: The property `categories` is still not found, so it resorts to `__toString()`. Does implementing `setCategories` help?

Comment: ah, okay... yes, you are right - He is looking at `__toString` right now. No, `setCategories` didn't help. Strange error, but I think we are getting closer to it.

Comment: Try changing the access modifier of `categories` in the entity class from `private` to `protected`. Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: no difference - same error.

Comment: Is `Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Category` correct in your entity mapping? In your form you have `CheckoutItemBundle:Category` which looks for `Checkout\ItemBundle\Entity\Category`.

Comment: no, it looks for `Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Category` - I checked it twice.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I would remove the `categories` property altogether and see if things work. If they do, then I'd try referencing another (very simple) entity in the `@ManyToMany` relation until I isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Select a Category',
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 'CheckoutItemBundle:Category',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $currentUser);
        },
    ))
```

You have a Many-To-Many relation, but your form expects a Many-To-One. To fix this behavior need to set `multiple` to `true`.